# After module install - mass CSS errors and menu problems

Tags: theming

Whilst I was installing the Form Builder UI module, the website semi-crashed - didn't load the page correctly.

Upon reloading it, the module was installed, however there were a tonne of errors, including:

- The PHP Filter Module became disabled
- There are huge CSS errors on the front page, particularly around the drop down menus (see [www.movingonios.co.uk](http://www.movingonios.co.uk) for details)
- The reports section from the Admin options is missing Status Report - no sign or error logs etc.

I have tried reenabling PHP filter module, and disabling form builder, but the problem persists. I have also tried clearing the Drupal cache.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport for Form Builder UI module and should be reported in it's issue queue, not asked here.

Comment: For anyone else who comes across this googling with a similar problem.

When the PHP filter module disables for whatever reason it also disabled every module that was a dependency.

By going back through the modules one by one and turning them back on the site went back to normal.

Will add this as an actual answer once my allotted 8 hours is up.